# Creating quick view of progress towards project completion in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I maintain mini-course completion records for several thousand students and need to provide their principals with a quick view of their progress towards completion.  Each Access record looks like this:
Name, Course, Date, Completed?(yes/no)
I have successfully created a query and report for an individual student but I would like to create a report that looks like a table with student names as row headings and course names as column headings and yes/no data filling in the table.  I think it may involve nested queries and I am new to SQL.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can there ever be more than one row for any combination of `Name` and `Course`?  Perhaps those fields might be the same in 2 rows but their `Date` values are different?

Comment: The same name and course could be in more than one row but not date.